# Old Linux machines support chronyd service?

Tags: ntp

We have installed OEL 8 NTP Server in our enviroment. My question is :  We have old linux server. Does support old linux machines to the chrony service ?

thanks,

Comment: Chrony dates from the 1990s, if I am not wrong. However, nobody can answer such a question, except you. Nobody knows how old this computer is and what OS it runs - except you. I run chrony on a seven years old computer (I think).

Comment: Why don't you tell us: What Linux distribution it is running? Tell us if you want to build Chrony or install it via a package manager?